# how to change format from yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm am/pm

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure. And I declared `CREATION_TIME` in a table variable:

My creation time format now like this: `2017-04-12 13:01:04.730`

I want to format it like `12/04/2017 13:01 PM`

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Dates are NOT stored with a format. They are stored as datetime. When you want a specific format it is best left to the front end application. But if you absolutely must format dates coming out of sql you need to use either the FORMAT function or CONVERT.

Comment: I used this function  CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), L.CreatedON, 103) but it doesn't work.  I used SSRS reporting Server but I just changed hour part.

Comment: Why can't you format the output in SSRS instead of trying to force the formatting from your query? If you are deadset on doing this in your query you are going to have to use FORMAT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Format() if 2012+

```
Declare @D datetime = '2017-04-12 13:01:04.730'
Select Format(@D,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt')
```

**Returns**

```
12/04/2017 01:01 PM
```

Notice the **hh** vs **HH**.  **hh** will supply 12 hours while **HH** will supply 24 hour.

Seems odd to create 13:01 **PM**

Answer (score 1):

For Older versions of SQL Server I mean older than 2012 when we didn't have `FORMAT()` function, you can use something like....

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) + ' ' 
    + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100) , 7))


Returns: 13/04/2017 3:53PM
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment suggesting to do it in SSRS.

Update the format property of your textbox/tablix to this:

dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt

(Swap day and month as required for UK/USA etc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really SSRS was also a lot easier to change the format.
I updated the format on ssrs
(Textbox properties - number - custom  dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt)
Thank you so much again:)